# Why are there two versions of boost and which does Ubuntu use?

Tags: 12.04, versions, boost

Maybe this is to do with my lack of knowledge when it comes to Ubuntu repositories but I'm trying to understand which versions of boost Ubuntu has available and which version is best to use.

When reading the description of the `libboost-all-dev` package it says "Boost version (currently 1.46)" but the version I've installed reports version `1.48.0.2`. Installing `libboost-all-dev` got me boost packages which all seem to be version `1.46.1-7ubuntu3 (precise)` but I've noticed other boost packages with a version of `1.48.0-3 (precise)`.

Could someone explain to me which version of boost a vanilla install of Ubuntu comes with (or perhaps how to find out which version of boost comes with a vanilla install of any particular version of Ubuntu) without having to perform an install?

And if anyone happens to know, why does the `libboost-all-dev` package report a different version from its description but seems actually get the version from the description, not those which correspond with its version?

Answer (score 1):

Well I seem to have discovered part of the answer in writing the question.

The web-interface to the package browser will allow you to find a [particular release's libraries](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libs/).

Still confused about the boost package versioning though!

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before installing `libboost-all-dev`?

If you did, you should have ended up with the latest version for 12.04, that is `1.48.0.2`.

Each Ubuntu release has a different "newest" version available, for example, 13.10 has `1.53.0.0` and 14.04 has `1.54.0.1`. Generally, you should stick with the version supplied in the official repositories unless you have a good reason not to, and update your system every now and then. Ubuntu updates are very stable, I for one update && upgrade all my servers daily.